# Cordova Firebase Authentication Step 7 " universal-links "

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, phonegap, google-signin

I follow the steps one by one [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova). But there is a problem in step 7.

Step 7 :

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN" scheme="https" />
    <host name="AUTH_DOMAIN" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

**When config.xml is added, "cordova run android" do not work.**

Config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.twobuddy.hybrtnkk" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>NeKadarKaldi</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-browsertab" spec="^0.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="^4.3.0">
        <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="com.twobuddy.hybrtnkk" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="ANDROID_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="ANDROID_PATHPREFIX" value="/" />
    </plugin>

<universal-links>
    <host name="DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN" scheme="https" />
    <host name="AUTH_DOMAIN" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>

    <plugin name="cordova-universal-links-plugin" spec="^1.2.1" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? "Doesn't work" is not very descriptive or helpful

Comment: You must to replace DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN and AUTH_DOMAIN with your owns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a modified version of the universal links plugin. It can be found here https://github.com/walteram/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Install it with `cordova plugin add https://github.com/walteram/cordova-universal-links-plugin.git`

This worked for me!

I found the answer here https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/issues/133

Comment: Please don't post questions as answer. Ask your question in the comments of the question.

Comment: Im trying the same, but im gettng this error N {code: "auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user", message: "The redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing."}

Answer (score 3):

I am using PhoneGap Build. The problem is Universal-links tag is not copied to AndroidManifest.xml. So the solution is

1. Install cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix
2. If you want to keep universal-links tag in config.xml keep it. But also add this to **config.xml**

**In widget tag on top add**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

The add following code **anywhere in config.xml** I prefer before plugins or beside unvirsal-links tag

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application/activity">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="****-***.firebaseapp.com" android:pathPrefix="/__/auth/callback" android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</config-file>
```

Now when app is build either with phonegapbuild or local cordova CLI, it copies the universal-links data which was supposed to be in manifest file. When app runs and firebase.auth().getRedirectResult() is called it will not give any error which was something like

*auth/cancelled by user. The redirect was cancelled by user before finalizing*

User building app using cordova CLI please after running cordova build android make sure you have the above intent-filter tag under activity tag in the manifest file.

Comment: Had the same issue with PhoneGap build, this is the only one working solution!